# HttpClient post returns bad request in c#, works in postman

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to access a rest endpoint, https://api.planet.com/auth/v1/experimental/public/users/authenticate. It is expecting json in the request body.

I can get the request to work in Postman but not using c#. Using postman I get the expected invalid email or password message but with my code I get "Bad Request" no matter I try.

Here is the code that makes the request

```
private void Login()
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.planet.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        //ClientDefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
        Data.User user = new Data.User
        {
            email = "myemail@company.com",
            password = "sdosadf"
        };
        var requestMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        var content = new StringContent(requestMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = client.PostAsync("auth/v1/experimental/public/users/authenticate", content).Result;
        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
    }
    catch (WebException wex )
    {
        MessageBox.Show(wex.Message) ;
    }
}
class User
{
    public string email;
    public string password;
}
```

Here are screen grabs form Postman that are working
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a proper value for the `MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue`?

Comment: are you setting an agent?

Comment: @DavidG yes I have tried setting //ClientDefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); but no luck

Comment: @SenadMeškin No I hadn't considered that, I will try now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to get this to work was to alter the content header "content-type". By default `HTTPClient`  was creating `content-type: application/json;characterset= UTF8`. I dropped and recreated the content header without the characterset section and it worked.

```
content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Dowlers.  I spent half a day yesterday puzzling over what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are trying to call an `async` method without waiting for the response using `await method` or `var task = method; task.Wait()` Therefore, when you end up doing `response.ToString()` it returns the text you are seeing.

One way to handle this within a non-async method would be to do the following:

```
var task = client.PostAsync("auth/v1/experimental/public/users/authenticate", content);
task.Wait();
var responseTask = task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
responseTask.Wait();
Console.WriteLine(responseTask.Result);
```

Another way is to make the current method async by doing `private async void Login()` and then do:

```
var postResp = await client.PostAsync("auth/v1/experimental/public/users/authenticate", content);
var response = await postResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

Comment: I tried both your suggestions but neither work. They do however change the error message slightly. When I wait for the task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() the message changes to "application/json required"

Comment: Thanks your suggestion led me to the eventual solution. When correctly read the result then new error message helped me figure out that the rest endpoint wasn't parsing my headers correctly. I had to drop and recreate the content-type header and it then worked.

Comment: Same here, didn't solve my bad request error directly, but improved the error message I was getting back (in the `response` object) to tell me my parameters weren't being parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Method Like this...

```
    static async Task<string> PostURI(Uri u, HttpContent c)
    {            

        var response = string.Empty;
        var msg = "";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(u, c);
             msg = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();              
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {                   
                response = result.StatusCode.ToString();                    

            }
        } 
        return response;
    }
```

call In your Method

```
public void Login()
    {
        string postData ="{\"email\":\"your_email\",\"password\":\"your_password\"}";
        Uri u = new Uri("yoururl");
        var payload = postData;

        HttpContent c = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
        var t = Task.Run(() => PostURI(u, c));
        t.Wait();
        Response.Write(t.Result);
    }
```